# How can I remove a trigger from a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm using the Task Scheduler cmdlet in PowerShell to configure triggers for a scheduled task of a Perfmon Data Collector set.
I'm using the following to modify the Scheduled task and start the data collector set when the server starts:

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\Microsoft\Windows\PLA\' -Taskname $TemplateName -Trigger $trigger
```

But I want to know if there is a way of removing this trigger from the scheduled task config.  I don't want to disable the Scheduled task, just want to remove this trigger from the Scheduled Task.

Doesn't look like there is a way of doing that from the PowerShell cmdlets.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a PowerShell cmdlet to delete a trigger, but you can do it through the Schedule.Service COM object.  The following example will remove the first trigger from the task named MyTask.

You may need to add a loop to inspect the triggers in order to find the specific trigger you want to remove based on the start time or other criteria.

**Note:** The trigger enumerations are one-based, not zero-based, so to remove the first trigger it is `$definition.Triggers.Remove(1)`

Credit to  [Changing Scheduled Tasks with PowerShell](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/06/21/changing-scheduled-tasks-with-powershell.aspx) for much of this.

```cs
$taskName = "MyTask"
$triggerToDelete = 1

# connect to Task Scheduler:
$service = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$service.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)

# pick a specific task in a container:
$folder = $service.GetFolder('\')
$task = $folder.GetTask($taskName)

# get task definition and change it:
$definition = $task.Definition
$definition.Triggers.Remove($triggerToDelete)

# write back changed task definition:
# 4 = Update
$folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task.Name, $definition, 4, $null, $null, $null)
```

To specifically delete all triggers that are "AtStartup" triggers, replace the `# get task definition and change it:` section with the following.  Note that it is looping through the triggers backwards, because if one is removed, the IDs of any following triggers change.

```
# get task definition and change it:
$definition = $task.Definition

$numTriggers = $definition.Triggers.Count

# loop backwards through the triggers and 
# remove any that are "Startup" (Type = 8)
for($triggerId=$numTriggers; $triggerId -gt 0; $triggerId--){
    if($definition.Triggers.Item($triggerId).Type -eq "8"){
        $definition.Triggers.Remove($triggerId)
    }
}
```

I'm sure this could be done with fewer lines by piping to a `where` clause, but it always takes me longer to get that right so I just loop through things as long as it's something that will have minimal impact.

Comment: Yes this is working well.
Thank you very much for all your assistance, really appreciated!

Comment: Although I did find a small error in the loop to remove all startup type triggers, if there were multiple Startup type triggers, it was only removing one of them, not all of them.
When you do the $definition.Triggers.Remove($triggerId), after it removes that trigger, the trigger count goes down by 1 and also the ids of triggers also change, get subtracted by 1.
Because of this, the loop doesn't check the trigger right after the one it just removed.

Comment: To correct it, I modified it this way:

`for($triggerId=1; $triggerId -le $definition.Triggers.Count; $triggerId++){    
    if($definition.Triggers.Item($triggerId).Type -eq "8"){        
        $definition.Triggers.Remove($triggerId);
        $triggerId-=1;
    }
}`

Comment: Good catch.  I assumed there would only be one startup trigger since having two doesn't make much sense, but there certainly can be two!

Comment: This does not work for some scheduled tasks - even when you run powershell in elevated mode, e.g. \Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\UpdateModelTask.