# How to change task triggers using powershell?

Tags: powershell

The script below removes the task triggers for each task ONLY if the tasks are in a folder. However my tasks are in the MAIN WINDOW in task scheduler. When you click on Task Scheduler Library, they are right there. They are not in any folder. However the $folder = $service.GetFolder('\') does not work. I tried it without the backlash and without the quotes, still does not work. What is going on ?

```
$service = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$service.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)

$folder = $service.GetFolder('\')

$tasks = $folder.gettasks(0)

foreach ($t in $tasks)
{
$definition = $t.Definition

$triggersCount = $definition.Triggers.Count

for($id=$triggersCount; $id -gt 0; $id--){
  $definition.Triggers.Remove($id)   
}

$folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($t.Name, $definition, 4, $null, $null, $null)
}
```

Comment: I have never done it this way as there are other tools for working with tasks.  However, if  I use empty quotes it seems to work: `$folder = $service.GetFolder('\')`.  Let me know how that goes.

Comment: I tried it with empty quotes too, still does not work. Is there another workaround? Is there something wrong with the script itself? the variables maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\"` may show all the tasks but there are no obvious commands or methods in the module to remove the triggers.  I couldn't see a way and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866202/4749264) seems to confirm it.

It's unclear from your question if `$folder = $service.GetFolder('\')` itself is producing an error, or if its the subsequent call to `$tasks = $folder.gettasks(0)`.  In this answer I'm assuming it's the latter, only because that's where I seem to have run into problems in my own environment.

I think this might be a combination of permissions and/or the hidden status of a task.  Firstly, can you try running as elevated?

Reason I think this is after `$folder = $service.GetFolder('\')` I was able to get a list of tasks in the root folder, however only 2 of 9 were listed. When I ran in elevated I got 6 of 9.

I even tried the old PowerShell pack "TaskScheduler" module, which internally uses pretty much the same COM code, and I got the same results.

Now I was finally able to get the COM approach to show all 9 in the elevated session by flipping the GetTasks argument to 1:

```
$tasks = $folder.gettasks(1)
```

I believe the argument means to show or not to show hidden tasks, however it only accepts an [Int]. So, 0 = false, 1 = true.  I confirmed this by looking at the code in the old "TaskScheduler" module.  Putting a Boolean like $true in the argument doesn't work, only an [Int] will do.

> Note: There is a hidden check box in the lower left, on the first tab
> of the Task properties dialog.  In may case the correlation matched what I ultimately found in the console.

At any rate give these 2 things a try:

1. Run as elevated.
2. Flip the argument to 1

Let me know how it turns out.  Thanks.

Comment: HEY. IT WORKED. Why does the 0 vs 1 make such a huge difference ?!

Comment: 1 just means show hidden tasks.  Everything is in the answer, but I figured that out by analyzing the code from the the "TaskScheduler" module which was from the Windows 7 Resource kit, also known as the PowerShell Pack.  Take a look at the tasks in the GUI and see if that check box is selected.  Also, and I don't mean to be pushy, but I put a good bit of time into this, please mark as answered and up-vote if you like.  Thanks!